# Intersection between two solutions of linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this linear differential equation :

$y'=4-x^2y^2$

I used this  [Slope field plotter](https://www.geogebra.org/m/W7dAdgqc) to get the solutions:

[image]

Why A , C solutions have some intersection points ? I thought it cant be intersect each other since we get two solutions for initial conditions.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no actual intersections: the solutions through A and C are just very very close together for $x < 0$.